# Reusing Prepared Statements, Transactions and Connection Pool

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, prepared-statement, connection-pooling

I am doing a school project in which my team has to ensure consistency and integrity of data, as well as to improve performance for a trading website. The website is coded in JSP and JAVA. We are also using MySQL and its ndb cluster for our project.

Firstly, I have done experiments on prepared statements with load test of 100, 175 and 250 virtual users. The results show that reusing prepared statements improves response time and throughput. By improvement, I meant that average response time decreases and maximum throughput increases.

Secondly, I have also done experiments using connection pool with the same load test of 100, 175 and 250 virtual users. Similarly, the results show an improvement in performance. Just an additional information, I used c3p0 for the connection pool.

With these results, I am planning to use prepared statements and connection pool for the trading website. At the same time, we would also use transactions to ensure consistency and integrity of data.

Currently, the way that I have implemented prepared statements and transaction are as follows:

```
public class ExchangeBean {
private PreparedStatement psSelectFromBuy = null;
private PreparedStatement psSelectFromSell = null;
private PreparedStatement psInsertBuy = null;
private PreparedStatement psInsertSell = null;
private Connection tranDbConnection = null;

public ExchangeBean() {
    reusePreparedStatements();
}

public void reusePreparedStatements() {
    tranDbConnection = DbBean.getDBConnection();
    dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);


    try {
        psSelectFromBuy = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM buy WHERE stock = ?" FOR UPDATE);
        psSelectFromSell = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sell WHERE stock = ?" FOR UPDATE);
        psInsertBuy = tranDbConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO buy (userid, date, price, stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
        psInsertSell = tranDbConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sell (userid, date, price, stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public boolean buy(//some parameters) {
    try {
        selectFromBuy(); //a method that contains psSelectFromBuy
        psInsertBuy.clearParameters();
        psInsertBuy.setInt(1, buy.getUserId());
        psInsertBuy.setLong(2, buy.getDate().getTime());
        psInsertBuy.setInt(3, buy.getPrice());
        psInsertBuy.setString(4, buy.getStock());
        psInsertBuy.executeUpdate();

        //some other codes
        psInsertBuy.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dbConnection.rollback();
    }
}

public boolean sell(//some parameters) {
    try {
        selectFromSell(); //a method that contains psSelectFromSell
        psInsertSell.clearParameters();
        psInsertSell.setInt(1, sell.getUserId());
        psInsertSell.setLong(2, sell.getDate().getTime());
        psInsertSell.setInt(3, sell.getPrice());
        psInsertSell.setString(4, sell.getStock());
        psInsertSell.executeUpdate();

        //some other codes
        psInsertSell.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dbConnection.rollback();
    }
}
}
```

*Note: This code sample is incomplete for brevity's sake; quite a fair bit of the codes and logic not in it.*

So basically, my approach is to declare the prepared statements as class variables and then instantiate them when the class is being called the very first time.

**Questions**

1. Is my approach correct? I feel that it is not exactly correct because all my prepared statements are tied to one connection. I am worried that if multiple users try to buy and sell at the same time, there may be issues since only one connection is used. However, I cannot close the connection else my prepared statements would be closed after each deal and hence would not be reused. Furthermore, when I commit, all the prepared statements involved in the transaction should be committed together and hence it would be easier if I only used one connection.
2. Do you have any suggestions on how I should use connection pooling with prepared statements and transactions? I was thinking of caching all the prepared statements into the connection each time it is created from the pool. When the connection is being used for buy or sell, the method itself will disable auto commit on that connection and enable auto commit again at the end of the method. Would this approach be appropriate? Or should I have two connection pools (one for non-transaction connections and one for transaction connections)?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this yourself. Your code is a) not thread safe, b) very hardcoded. c3p0 supports [statement pooling](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling) out of the box. I would suggest you **carefully** read the entire page for c3p0 before you start using it. Further, you should get a connection from the pool in **the smallest possible scope** as they are a scarce resource. In short, this is **not** the correct approach.

Comment: While re-using prepared statements can have a positive performance impact during testing, it rarely has a significant effect during production. Database network latency and ACID compliant settings like [these](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12612) will determine the performance. Connection pooling on the other hand is always a good idea.

Comment: Hi Boris, I have read the c3p0's page on statement pooling (http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling) but there is one thing I am unsure of. If I prepared a statement in this connection before and I re-prepare the statement on the same connection, will the connection be smart enough to know that this statement has been prepared before and use back the previously prepared statement?

Comment: Hi vanOekel, would you still advise against reusing prepared statements even if there is a case for statement pooling using connection pool?